# Fitch Questions Please Help Me

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

I'm having trouble understanding writing out a proof. The proof I'm trying to work with is :

[image]

How do I reach this goal? Which rules do I use and with which support steps to each rule (proofs to prove each step?) Using only inference rules, reit, quantifier rules.

Comment: Do not edit out the question once you have an answer.  (Though you should *replace* the image with text, you should *not* just delete it to leave no context for future readers..)

Answer (score 2):

This is only a description of the justifications for the steps. How you describe the justifications in the proof checker will depend on that tool.

Lines 5 and 6 used universal elimination to replace the variable *x* with the name *a*. You will likely need to reference which lines were used.

Line 8 used conditional elimination which should reference the conditional on line 6 and its antecedent on line 7. This gives you the consequent.

Similarly line 9 used conditional elimination which should reference the conditional on line 5 and its antecedent on line 8. This allows you to derive the consequent.

Line 10 derives the contradiction between lines 9 and 4. This is contradiction introduction.

Line 11 derives the negation of the assumption on line 7 discharging the subproof on lines 7 to 10. This is negation introduction.

Line 12 uses existential introduction. This is copied to the last line where existential elimination was used. This existential elimination began with the assumption on line 4 replacing the variable *x* in line 3 with the name *a*. This subproof was able to be closed when a line was derived that did not use the name *a*. That happened on line 12.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete proof with all steps justified in the Fitch program. [image]